# Adding TFS tasks (work item) via url

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

Currently i'm trying something out with TFS 2015. I red that it should be possible to add tasks (work-items) via the browser url. This is perfect for me if it is working like I expected :)

My current url (personal items removed)

> https://{myurl}/tfs/DefaultCollection/{project}/_workItems#_a=new&witd=Task&[Title]=Do
>   this&[Original Estimate]=1&[Remaining
>   Work]=1&**[??????PARENT?????]={??id??}**&[System.AreaPath]={project}&[System.IterationPath]={project+iteration}

So far so good it's possible to add an item via the url, but I couldn't figure out how to add the **parent link to the work item**!
I've tried [Node Name], [Parent], [System.NodeName], but none of them worked.

Does anyone have an idea how to create the link? Or is it not possible?

tnx in advance

Comment: this looks like you're using the client URL and not the API URL to create this work item. Have you looked at this link [Create a work item (with a work item link)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-a-work-item-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use *[System.Linktypes]* or *[System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse]*

Moreover, suggest you to use **REST API** just as *debugthings* mentioned. [Work Items|Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#with-a-work-item-link) If you haven't already, look at the information on [getting started](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics) with these APIs.